# Normalizing histogram bins in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, histogram, normalize, bins

I'm trying to plot a histogram whose bins are normalized by the number of elements in the bin.

I'm using the following

```
binwidth=5
bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width) + binwidth/2.0
plot 'file' using (bin($2, binwidth)):($4) smooth freq with boxes
```

to get a basic histogram, but I want the value of each bin to be divided by the size of the bin. How can I go about this in gnuplot, or using external tools if necessary?

Answer (score 9):

In gnuplot 4.4, functions take on a different property, in that they can execute multiple successive commands, and then return a value (see [gnuplot tricks](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/2010/01/further-new-features-in-gnuplot-44.html)) This means that you can actually calculate the number of points, n, within the gnuplot file without having to know it in advance. This code runs for a file, "out.dat", containing one column: a list of n samples from a normal distribution:

```
binwidth = 0.1
set boxwidth binwidth
sum = 0

s(x)          = ((sum=sum+1), 0)
bin(x, width) = width*floor(x/width) + binwidth/2.0

plot "out.dat" u ($1):(s($1))
plot "out.dat" u (bin($1, binwidth)):(1.0/(binwidth*sum)) smooth freq w boxes
```

The first plot statement reads through the datafile and increments sum once for each point, plotting a zero.

The second plot statement actually uses the value of sum to normalise the histogram.

Comment: You can improve this even more by letting the second value of `s(x)` be `NaN`, and adding `notitle` to the first `plot` command - that way, the summation will be completely invisible in the figure, since gnuplot ignores `NaN` values when plotting =)

Answer (score 8):

In gnuplot 4.6, you can count the number of points by `stats` command, which is faster than `plot`.  Actually, you do not need such a trick `s(x)=((sum=sum+1),0)`, but directly count the number by variable `STATS_records` after running of `stats 'out.dat' u 1`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I would do, with n=500 random gaussian variates generated from R with the following command:

```
Rscript -e 'cat(rnorm(500), sep="\\n")' > rnd.dat
```

I use quite the same idea as yours for defining a normalized histogram, where y is defined as 1/(binwidth * n), except that I use `int` instead of `floor` and I didn't recenter at the bin value. In short, this is a quick adaptation from the [smooth.dem](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/smooth.html) demo script, and a similar approach is described in Janert's textbook, *[Gnuplot in Action](http://www.manning.com/janert/)* ([Chapter 13](http://www.manning.com/janert/SampleCh13.pdf), p. 257, freely available). You can replace my sample data file with `random-points` which is available in the `demo` folder coming with Gnuplot. Note that we need to specify the number of points as Gnuplot as no counting facilities for records in a file.

```
bw1=0.1
bw2=0.3
n=500
bin(x,width)=width*int(x/width)
set xrange [-3:3]
set yrange [0:1]
tstr(n)=sprintf("Binwidth = %1.1f\n", n) 
set multiplot layout 1,2
set boxwidth bw1
plot 'rnd.dat' using (bin($1,bw1)):(1./(bw1*n)) smooth frequency with boxes t tstr(bw1)
set boxwidth bw2
plot 'rnd.dat' using (bin($1,bw2)):(1./(bw2*n)) smooth frequency with boxes t tstr(bw2)
```

Here is the result, with two bin width

[image]

Besides, this really is a rough approach to histogram and more elaborated solutions are readily available in R. Indeed, the problem is how to define a good bin width, and this issue has already been discussed on [stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/798/calculating-optimal-number-of-bins-in-a-histogram-for-n-where-n-ranges-from-30-3): using [Freedman-Diaconis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedman%E2%80%93Diaconis_rule) binning rule should not be too difficult to implement, although you'll need to compute the inter-quartile range.

Here is how R would proceed with the same data set, with default option (Sturges rule, because in this particular case, this won't make a difference) and equally spaced bin like the ones used above.

[image]

The R code that was used is given below:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2), las=1)
hist(rnd, main="Sturges", xlab="", ylab="", prob=TRUE)
hist(rnd, breaks=seq(-3.5,3.5,by=.1), main="Binwidth = 0.1", 
     xlab="", ylab="", prob=TRUE)
```

You can even look at how R does its job, by inspecting the values returned when calling `hist()`:

```
> str(hist(rnd, plot=FALSE))
List of 7
 $ breaks     : num [1:14] -3.5 -3 -2.5 -2 -1.5 -1 -0.5 0 0.5 1 ...
 $ counts     : int [1:13] 1 1 12 20 49 79 108 87 71 43 ...
 $ intensities: num [1:13] 0.004 0.004 0.048 0.08 0.196 0.316 0.432 0.348 0.284 0.172 ...
 $ density    : num [1:13] 0.004 0.004 0.048 0.08 0.196 0.316 0.432 0.348 0.284 0.172 ...
 $ mids       : num [1:13] -3.25 -2.75 -2.25 -1.75 -1.25 -0.75 -0.25 0.25 0.75 1.25 ...
 $ xname      : chr "rnd"
 $ equidist   : logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "histogram"
```

All that to say that you can use R results to process your data with Gnuplot if you like (although I would recommend to use R directly :-).

Answer (score 2):

Another way of counting the number of data points in a file is by using a system command. This proves useful if you are plotting multiple files, and you don't know the number of points beforehand. I used:

```
countpoints(file) = system( sprintf("grep -v '^#' %s| wc -l", file) )
file1count = countpoints (file1)
file2count = countpoints (file2)
file3count = countpoints (file3)
...
```

The `countpoints` functions avoids counting lines that start with '#'. You would then use the already mentioned functions to plot the normalized histogram.

Here's a complete example:

```
n=100
xmin=-50.
xmax=50.
binwidth=(xmax-xmin)/n

bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width)+width/2.0
countpoints(file) = system( sprintf("grep -v '^#' %s| wc -l", file) )

file1count = countpoints (file1)
file2count = countpoints (file2)
file3count = countpoints (file3)

plot file1 using (bin(($1),binwidth)):(1.0/(binwidth*file1count)) smooth freq with boxes,\
     file2 using (bin(($1),binwidth)):(1.0/(binwidth*file2count)) smooth freq with boxes,\
     file3 using (bin(($1),binwidth)):(1.0/(binwidth*file3count)) smooth freq with boxes
...
```

Answer (score -2):

Simply

```
plot 'file' using (bin($2, binwidth)):($4/$4) smooth freq with boxes
```

Comment: Can you please add some context around your answer. It will help the asker and readers both.

Comment: What to say? It's the straight answer to shivknight's question. By using `($4/$4)` or `(1)` instead of just `($4)` one obtains the count of the elements instead of their sum.