# Plot with 2D histograms bins

Tags: gnuplot, histogram2d

I have seen in posts [Normalizing histogram bins in Gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787096/normalizing-histogram-bins-in-gnuplot) that is possible to bin some x samples and plot a histogram, with

```
binwidth=5
bin(x,width)=width*floor(x/width) + binwidth/2.0
plot 'file.dat' using (bin($1, binwidth)):(1/(binwidth*num_points) smooth freq with boxes
```

I would like to achieve the same result of that post but with the 2D dataset ((x,y)-points) and plot a type of heat map of that data, for example with heat-map indicating the probability, or intensity (i.e. (number of samples)/(bin area)).

How could I compute the 2d-bin_plot with `Gnuplot`?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binning of 2D data is the same principle as for 1D. The special point about it is that the option `smooth freq` which is used for 1D binning will only accept one value for the bins (not two: x and y).
Hence, you simply enumerate your bins from `0` to `BinCountX * BinCountY - 1` and define functions `BinValueX(), BinValueY()` to get back from your bin number to the x- and y-bin values.

The test data section creates random x,y and z-values. The z-values within a x,y-bin will be added during the binning process.

Alternatively, depending on the data, a [density plot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53751188/7295599) could also be of interest.

**Script:** (works with gnuplot>=5.0.0)

```
### 2D binning of data
reset session

# create some random test data
set table $Data
    set samples 5000
    plot '+' u (invnorm(rand(0))):(invnorm(rand(0))):(int(rand(0)*10+1)) w table
    set samples 1000
    plot '+' u (invnorm(rand(0))+2):(invnorm(rand(0))+2):(int(rand(0)*10+1)) w table
unset table

BinWidthX = 0.25
BinWidthY = 0.25

# get data range min, max
stats $Data u 1:2 nooutput
Xmin = floor(STATS_min_x/BinWidthX)*BinWidthX
Ymin = floor(STATS_min_y/BinWidthY)*BinWidthY
Xmax = ceil(STATS_max_x/BinWidthX)*BinWidthX
Ymax = ceil(STATS_max_y/BinWidthY)*BinWidthY

BinCountX      = int((Xmax-Xmin)/BinWidthX)
BinCountY      = int((Ymax-Ymin)/BinWidthY)
XYtoBinNo(x,y) = (floor((y-Ymin)/BinWidthY))*BinCountX + floor((x-Xmin)/BinWidthX)
BinNoToX(n)    = Xmin + (int(n)%BinCountX)*BinWidthX
BinNoToY(n)    = Ymin + (int(n)/BinCountY)*BinWidthY   # integer division!

# get data into bins
set table $Bins
    plot [*:*][*:*] $Data u (XYtoBinNo($1,$2)):3 smooth freq
unset table

set size ratio -1
set xrange [Xmin:Xmax]
set yrange [Ymin:Ymax]
set key noautotitle
set style fill solid 1.0
set grid x,y

set multiplot layout 1,2

    set title "Raw data"
    plot $Data u 1:2:3 w p pt 7 ps 0.2 lc palette
    
    set title "2D binned data"
    dx=BinWidthX*0.5
    dy=BinWidthY*0.5
    plot $Bins u (BinNoToX($1)+dx):(BinNoToY($1)+dy):(dx):(dy):2 w boxxy fc palette z
unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]